# How do you determine a given word's line index using MapReduce techniques in MrJob?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mapreduce, multiprocessing, mrjob

I would like to create an inverted index using MapReduce techniques with MrJob. The inverted index for a given word `x` is defined as the line index or indices where `x` occurs in a given input text file. For example, say `x` is the word `this` and the input text file `text.txt` is:

```
# copyright laws for your country before downloading or redistributing 
# this or any other Project Gutenberg eBook. BLANK LINE BELOW.

# This header should be the first thing seen when viewing this Project 
# Gutenberg file.  Please do not remove it.
```

Then the inverted index for `this` would be:

```
"this": 2, 4, 4
```

Since `this` occurs on line `2` and twice on line `4`. Noting case insensitivity.

Comment: What is your question?  All you have done is to state a general desire -- there is no Stack Overflow question in this.  Please repeat the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  SO is neither a coding service nor a tutorial resource.  We will help you diagnose a *specific* problem with *your* code -- which you have not posted.

Comment: @Prune I don't have any relevant code as I don't even know how to approach the problem in MrJob. I have searched online for possible solutions to no avail.

Comment: This typically is not something for which you "find" a solution -- you work through tutorials for the needed programming tools and *create* a solution.  That process is well outside the scope of Stack Overflow's stated purpose.  In general, when you can't write *any* code towards solving your problem, then it's likely not a SO question.  Rather, you need tutorial resources or an open-ended help site.

Comment: As side notes: (1) Why do you need to do this with MapReduce? (2) Why do you need to do this through Hadoop?  There are many available indexing tools -- look for text-processing and NLP (natural-language processing) packages -- that might do the task for you without resorting to the overhead of learning extra implementation tools.

Comment: In response to both 1&2 in order to efficiently compute inverted indices of let's say a large library of documents(on the order of GBs) by using shared computing resources on a cluster as enabled by Hadoop. Also chances are those other indexing tools probably end up interfacing with Hadoop in the background, if there are doing it effieciently anyways.